# Linear algebra done right proof exercise 13 (3.A)

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem:Suppose $v_1,...,v_m$ is a linearly dependent list of vectors in V. Suppose also that $W \neq \{0\}$. Prove there exist $w_1,...,w_m \in W$ such that no $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ satisfies $Tv_k=w_k$ for each $k=1,...,m$

Attempt:

Try to define a transformation $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ by

$T(a_1v_1+\dots+a_mv_m)=a_1w_1+\dots +a_mw_m$

Since $v_1,...,v_m$ is linearly dependent there exist scalars $a_1,...,a_m$ not all zero such that

$a_1v_1+\dots+a_mv_m=0$

Let $j$ be the largest index in $\{1,...,m\}$ such that $a_j \neq 0$

Hence $a_j=-\frac{a_{j-1}}{{a_j}}v_{j-1}-\dots-\frac{a_1}{a_j}v_1$

Thus

$a_1Tv_1+\dots+a_{j-1}Tv_{j-1}+T(-\frac{a_{j-1}}{{a_j}}v_{j-1}-\dots-\frac{a_1}{a_j}v_1)+\dots+a_mTv_m=a_{j+1}Tv_{j+1}+\dots+a_mTv_m$

Then attempting to set $a_{j+1}Tv_{j+1}+\dots+a_mTv_m=a_1w_1+\dots+a_mw_m$

Since there are $m-j$ vectors on the left hand side and $m$ vectors on the right hand side, the transformation cannot be defined as wanted.

Is this the correct way to prove this?Any suggestions?

Comment: In order to prove your statement, you need to define clearly what the vectors $w_1,\ldots ,w_m$ can be. It does not appear in your proof, so it is incomplete for now. You're on the good way though.

Answer (score 4):

Since you did not say how you choose the $w_i$'s your proof is not correct.

There exist scalars $a_i$ nor all $0$ such that $ \sum a_iv_i=0$. Suppose $a_k \neq 0$. Pick any $w_k \neq 0$ in $W$ and let $w_i=0$ for  $ i \neq k$. If there exists a linear map $T:V \to W$ such that $Tv_i=w_i$ for all $i$ then $0=T( \sum a_iv_i)= \sum a_iT(v_i)=a_kw_k$ which is a contradiction. Hence no such $T$ exists.

Comment: Do you mean let $w_i=0$ for $i \neq k$?

Comment: @68e1515 Yes, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I have one question when defining the transformation on the vector $v_k$, are you defining it as $Tv_k=w_k$ like you would on a basis vector? Then mapping the rest of the $v_i's$ to zero.Sorry I am still having trouble understanding the proof completely. So you are defining $T(v_i)=w_i$ for $i=k$ and $T(v_i)=0$ for $i \neq k$?

Comment: all the $w's$ are zero except $w_k$. Then if $Tv_i=w_i$ you get a contradiction.

Comment: What the question says is (for suitable choice of $w_i$'s) there is no LT $T$ such that $Tv_i=w_i$ for all $i$. For this we don't have to define $T$. We only define $w_i$'s, assume that there exists some LT $T$ such that $Tv_i=w_i$ for  all $i$ and get  a contradiction.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still having trouble understanding does the $0$ come from applying the transformation to $\Sigma a_iv_i=0$? I just simply cannot understand your  proof

Comment: $T$ is assumed to be linear. So $T(0)=0$ and  $0=\sum a_i v_i$ gives $0=T(0)=T(\sum a_i v_i)=\sum a_i T(v_i)=\sum a_i w_i=a_kw_k$. @68e1515

Comment: What if we choose two vectors $w_k$ and $w_j$ to lie in the range of the transformation instead of just $w_k$ would we get the same result, a contradiction?What if we choose all the $w's$ except for one to lie in the range, do we still get a contradiction?

Comment: Would this question have the same answer if we choose all the $w_i,s$ to lie in the range of the transformation since in the end all the vectors would end up equaling zero?

Comment: It is important to note that the only assumption on $W$ is that it is not $\{0\}$. It can even be one-dimensional. So the only freedom we have is to take one non-zero vector in it. This is what I did in my answer.

Comment: $0$ is also in the range of $T$ so your choice will not give an answer to the question.